# Create [timepiece] tag

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I just posted this question: [How to accurately set the date on an analog watch?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/how-to-accurately-set-the-date-on-an-analog-watch), and noticed that there is no tag for questions relating to timepieces (watches, clocks, and other devices that indicate the time).  I used the [time](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) tag, but according to its wiki, it isn't really a good fit.

I don't have enough rep on this site to create a tag.  If it is likely that mine will not remain the only timepiece question, can someone with sufficient rep create a [timepiece](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timepiece) tag and add it to my question?